# Checking if an attribute gets attached to $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This question really consists of two:

1 - Do functions create their own $scopes in javasript?

```
e.g.$scope.foo = function() {
    $scope.bar = "Bar";    
}
```

I ask this because in one such test that I'm trying to run I check to determine the existence of a variable on the scope, run a function and then recheck:

```
 iit('getPatientFirstName should attach patientName to the scope', function() {
    // Passes
    expect(scope.patientName).toBeUndefined();
    spyOn(scope,'getPatientFirstName').andCallThrough();
    scope.getPatientFirstName(detailsBody);

    // Fails
    expect(scope.patientName)not.toBeUndefined();
});

 // In the controller
 $scope.getPatientFirstName = function (dataBody) {
        $scope.patientName = dataBody.patientFirstName;
 };
```

So this suggests that they may have their own scope? If this is the case can we test this?

2 - Is a valid alternative just to use an object that exists outside the function:

```
 $scope.patientDetails = {
        patientName: ''
 };

 $scope.getPatientFirstName = function (dataBody) {
        $scope.patientDetails.patientName = dataBody.patientFirstName;
 };
```

Thanks

**EDIT**
Considering the two answers has raised another question - is a variable (attribute or object) considered global if its attached to the $scope? It can be accessed in any function in that controller but as far as being called in a completely different controller - yes it can?

Confirm/Deny anyone?

And it appears that assigning the variable to the $scope global is considered valid for the purposes of my test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your first questions, **no**, functions do not create new `$scopes` by their own (note that we are talking about *scopes* and not *closures*, which are two different concepts).

In your example, the `$scope.foo` function creates a new `bar` property on the same `$scope` object where `foo` is defined. The final `$scope` object would look something like this:

```
$scope {
  foo: function() {
    $scope.bar = "Bar";    
  },
  bar: "Bar"
}
```

The problem with your test may be related to the missing `.` before the `not`.

```
expect(scope.patientName).not.toBeUndefined();
```

> Is a valid alternative just to use an object that exists outside the
>   function:

**Yes**, you can use an object that's defined outside the function.

If the object is on the same `$scope` object you will have no problems, just make sure it is defined *before* you run the function, otherwise you will get a `$scope.patientDetails is not defined` error.

Comment: that .not is in my test - i actually didn't copy and paste the code above - just typed it out so thats why it isn't there.

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer the question a little differently than where you are taking it.  I hope it helps you to rethink your stategy.

1 - Do functions create their own $scopes in javasript?
They do create an own scope.  But the surrounding scope is also available within the scope.  So when you write a function within a function, the inner function can use all the variables of the outer function

Example

```
function foo() {
  var a=5;
  function bar() {
    var b=4;
  }
  function hello() {
    var c=3;
  }
}
```

a is available for all the functions, foo, bar and hello.
b is not available for foo nor for hello. 
c is not available for foo nor for bar.

2 - Is a valid alternative just to use an object that exists outside the function:
So, you should try to make an outer function; there you can declare variables that will be strictly contained within that outer function.
Any function you create within this outer function can make use of that outer scope.

Variables that are global should be avoided if possible.

---

An example: jQuery.

jQuery has 1 variable that is global: var jQuery ( You can also access it by its alias $ ).
The variables that jQuery uses will not be in conflict with any variables you use.
And anything you want from jQuery, you will have to go through $ (or jQuery)

Comment: I'm aware that javascript operates in patriarchal-like way - in that child functions have access to parent scopes but parent don't have access to child scope. But is a variable considered global if its on the scope? I thought it would be considered global if its declared as var

Comment: It's (kind of) the other way around.  When you use var the variable is set in the local scope.  When you declare a variable without var the variable will be set to global.

Comment: ah ok - i'll test that out

Comment: @EmmanuelDelay I believe you are mixing up 2 concepts here. The type of **Scopes** OP is talking about, are an Angular concept, not the general *scope* concept. Also, take a look at JS [Strict mode](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_strict.asp).

Comment: Ah, okay. It might have been a good idea to mention Angular.js in the question.